# Junit Test cases for update and get

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have these two functions in my userServiceImpl class. I want to write their test cases. I am completely new to this so cannot figure out how to write the jUnit test cases.

```
    public UserDto updateUser(String userId, UserDto user) {
        UserEntity userEntity = this.userRepository.findByUserId(userId);

        if (userEntity == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with ID: " + userId + " not found");

        userEntity.setName(user.getName());
        userEntity.setCity(user.getCity());
        userEntity.setAddress(user.getAddress());
        userEntity.setPhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber());

        UserEntity updatedUserDetails = userRepository.save(userEntity);
        return new ModelMapper().map(updatedUserDetails, UserDto.class);

    }

    @Override
    public List<UserDto> getUsers(int page, int limit) {
        List<UserDto> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();

        Pageable pageableRequest = PageRequest.of(page, limit);
        Page<UserEntity> usersPage = this.userRepository.findAll(pageableRequest);
        List<UserEntity> users = usersPage.getContent();
    //loop on list of users and create new userdto for each user
        for (UserEntity userEntity : users) {
            UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEntity, userDto);
            returnValue.add(userDto);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

I tried writing the test case for updateUser but it failed

**testUpdateUser**

```
    final void testUpdateUser() {
        
        when(userRepository.save(any(UserEntity.class))).thenReturn(userEntity);
        
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        UserDto storedDetails = userService.updateUser("edsd3445tcd", userDto);

        assertNotNull(storedDetails);
        
    }
```

Please help me with these two test cases.

Comment: Please provide the test setup. Do you use an in memory database or do you use mocks?

Comment: I have used mocks

Comment: I assume, you have injected a Mock userRepository into userService. The call updateUser will first call findByUserId and there is no teaching for this in the test. I assume the test fails with UsernameNotFoundException?

Comment: Yes I have injected userRepository as mock. How can I resolve this issue of UsernameNotFoundException?

Comment: You'll need another teaching like 'when(userRepository.findByUserId("edsd3445tcd")).thenReturn(userEntity);'

Comment: You should add a tag 'mockito' to the question.

Comment: SaschaDoerdelmann thanks! it worked for me... also how can I write the test case for the getUsers method

Comment: As you did not accept my answer, yet: Where do you stuck with either the test case for the updateUser or the getUsers method?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments: The method findByUserId of the Mock is called but the call is not part of the teaching. The Mock will return null and therefore we get an UsernameNotFoundException.

Solution: add the missing when(userRepository.findByUserId(...))...;

I also suggest to use an ArgumentCaptor to be able to add some assertions.
Without the capture, you won't see, if the changes will be saved.

Variable userEntity seems to be a member variable. I would rather use two  local variables, one to represent the state at the first teaching and one to represent the state at the second teaching.

```
final void testUpdateUser() {
    
    var id = "edsd3445tcd";
    var userEntityBeforeChange = new UserEntity();
    userEntityBeforeChange.setId(id);
    userEntityBeforeChange.setName("Old Name");
    // ... set more attributes ...

    var userEntityAfterChange = new UserEntity();
    userEntityAfterChange.setId(id);
    userEntityAfterChange.setName("Changed Name");
    // ... set more attributes ...

    when(userRepository.findByUserId(id)).thenReturn(userEntityBeforeChange);
    ArgumentCaptor<UserEntity> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(UserEntity.class);
    when(userRepository.save(argument.capture())).thenReturn(userEntityAfterChange);
    
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    userDto.setName("New Name");
    // ... set more attributes ...
    UserDto storedDetails = userService.updateUser(id, userDto);

    assertEquals(userDto.getName(), argument.getValue().getName());
    assertNotNull(storedDetails);
    assertEquals(userEntityAfterChange.getName(), storedDetails.getName());
    // ... assertions for other attributes ...
    
}
```

Testing getUsers works in the same way: Teach the mock that there will be a call of findAll, call getUsers and finish with some assertions.